# Usando Programação Funcional LISP, responda aos exercícios?

Tags: lisp

Suponha que foram definidos:

```
(defun xxx (x) (+ 1 x)) (setf xxx 5)
```

Qual o valor das seguintes expressões?

1. (xxx 2)
2. (xxx (+ (xxx 5) 3))
3. (+ 4 xxx)
4. (xxx xxx)

Comment: Porque você não testa isso num interpretador de lisp e vê a resposta? Ou você quer uma explicação sobre a resposta dada?

Comment: Dica, ao testar, use `(print (xxx 2))`, por exemplo.

Comment: Estou aprendendo LISP por conta e não estou entendendo muito bem gostaria de entender nem que fosse com 1 exemplo só o resto me viro !

Comment: Veja esse site: http://rextester.com/l/common_lisp_online_compiler

Comment: Deu certo nesse exemplo do xxx 2 , deu 3 como resultado !. Gostaria de entender a resposta dada .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso daqui define `xxx` como uma função que soma 1 a `xxx`:

```
(defun xxx (x) (+ 1 x))
```

Isso daqui define `xxx` como tendo o valor 5:

```
(setf xxx 5)
```

O LISP mantém valores e funções separados. Ou seja, você tem uma variável `xxx` com o valor 5 e uma função `xxx` que soma mais um.

1. Quando você faz isso:

   ```
   (print (xxx 2))
   ```

   Você está chamando a função `xxx` e passando-lhe 2 como parâmetro. O resultado é 3.
2. Com isso:

   ```
   (print (xxx (+ (xxx 5) 3)))
   ```

   Você está chamando a função `xxx` e passando-lhe 5 como parâmetro, resultando em 6. Depois soma 3, que dá 9. Chama a função `xxx` de novo passando o 9, e dá 10.
3. Já nisso:

   ```
   (print (+ 4 xxx))
   ```

   O `xxx` é o número 5. Somando com 4 dá 9.
4. Finalmente, isso:

   ```
   (print (xxx xxx))
   ```

   Você chama a função `xxx` com o valor do `xxx` (que é 5). Logo, isso resulta em 6.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no rextester.**](http://rextester.com/ZCSG42081)

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Deu para entender bem com sua resposta, ajudou bastante . Grato!

Comment: Até eu aprendi agora, @GustavoAryel marque como aceita a resposta.